# Identify 40-pin PDIP device with top marking: TEZ C18071S 133807

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I'm trying to find a data sheet for C18071S but can't find any references to this component anywhere. It's a 40pin PDIP. Any help most welcome!

Edit: Added schematic. I hope this will help identification.

[image: Image of IC]
[image: Schematic]

Comment: Mike - Hi, FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you can supply from that list, the better the chances of identification. For example, what is the functionality of the overall PCB/product? What other components are close to that one, which might help to narrow down the choices of possible functionality of that device? etc. Please [edit] the question to add any new information or photos. Thanks.

Comment: It may well be some mask-programmed microprocessor or even more problematic, an ASIC, specifically made for that product, and no longer available even from the manufacturer. What next?

Comment: @SamGibson, thanks for the suggestion! Added schema.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, yes, quite possible. I did however find the the type number, including "TAZ", on this site: http://chip-sale.com/catalog9/cat/3325.php, so hopefully it's not an ASIC.

Comment: @Mike - Thanks for adding that partial schematic. It's certainly strange! Is there anything else you can add from that list e.g. what does the overall system / product do? Do you have any more of the schematic? A wider-angle photo to show surrounding components? Do you have any idea what function the IC might perform, based on your knowledge of the overall system and research so far? I presume that this unknown IC is D8 in the schematic. It seems that D7, D9-D11 perform some sort of 15V-to-10V translation. Any more details of them? D8 is annotated "3-PH WRS" - does 3-phase make sense?

Comment: @SamGibson D7, D9 etc are level shifters, MC14504. I do not now much about the application. I'm afraid I can't reveal more due to, among other things, copy right issues.

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer, but Google search suggests it is an obsolete inverter controller.  Since several sources purport to sell it, why not try contacting those sellers for more detail?

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, google turned up more answers than duckduckgo. I mailed one of the sources and asked for a quote on 25pcs, but they had no stock at this time. I will try a few others.